# Difference between a parametrized surface and manifold

Tags: manifolds, parametrization

What is the difference between a parametrized surface and manifold?

Is it true that if $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an $n$-dimensional parametrized surface it is also a (parametrized?) manifold? I am stuck with understanding the concept of a manifold. In which cases would a parametrized surface not be parametrized manifold or vice versa?

Comment: Roughly speaking, manifolds are kind of like the union of several parametrized surfaces with certain restrictions when the surfaces overlap.

Comment: So if I have a family of $(S_i)_i$ of parametrized surfaces, then the manifold is $\bigcup_i S_i $, but overlaps "count only once"?

Comment: As a set, yes. But generally we require the parametrizations be consistent on the overlapped part, so maybe not all family could become manifolds by union.